# getting Error While using Date picker class ActionSheetDatePicker.init

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker

> Hi I have a requirement where I need to show date in uiactionsheet

> my IBOutlet

```
@IBOutlet weak var dobTextField: UITextField!
```

> Here I call function when I tapped on date field

```
if textField == dobTextField {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        super.datePickerTapped { (dateString) in
            self.dobTextField.text = dateString
        }
        return false
    }
```

and this is a function which I called after tap on date field

```
func datePickerTapped(completionHandler: @escaping ((String)->Void)) {
        
        let cancelButton:UIButton =  UIButton(type: .custom)
        cancelButton.setTitle("Cancel", for: .normal)
        cancelButton.titleLabel?.font = crudFonts.appRegularFont
        cancelButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
        cancelButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 55, height: 25)
        
        let doneButton:UIButton =  UIButton(type: .custom)
        doneButton.setTitle("Done", for: .normal)
        doneButton.titleLabel?.font = crudFonts.appRegularFont
        doneButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
        doneButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 55, height: 25)
        
        let maxiumDate = Calendar.init(identifier: Calendar.Identifier.gregorian).date(byAdding: .year, value: -18, to: Date())
        let picker = ActionSheetDatePicker.init(title: "Date of Birth", datePickerMode: .date, selectedDate: maxiumDate, doneBlock: { (picker, selectedIndex, selectedValue) in
            
            if let date = selectedIndex as? Date {
                let formatter = DateFormatter()
                formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/YYYY"
                completionHandler(formatter.string(from: date))
            }
        }, cancel: { (picker) in
            
        }, origin: Global.getTopMostViewController()?.view)

        picker?.minimumDate = Calendar.init(identifier: Calendar.Identifier.gregorian).date(byAdding: .year, value: -100, to: Date())
        picker?.maximumDate = maxiumDate

        picker?.toolbarButtonsColor = .black
        picker?.toolbarBackgroundColor = UIColor.white
        picker?.setCancelButton(UIBarButtonItem(customView: cancelButton))
        picker?.setDoneButton(UIBarButtonItem(customView: doneButton))
        
        picker?.show()
        
        if let datePicker = picker?.pickerView as? UIDatePicker {
            if #available(iOS 13.4, *) {
                datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = UIDatePickerStyle.wheels
            }
        }
    }
```

Error :- Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

on this line :-  `let picker = ActionSheetDatePicker.init(title: "Date of Birth",   datePickerMode: .date, selectedDate: maxiumDate, doneBlock: { (picker, selectedIndex, selectedValue) in`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like one of the following two issues -

```
// This returns an optional date `Date?`
let maxiumDate = Calendar.init(identifier: Calendar.Identifier.gregorian).date(byAdding: .year, value: -18, to: Date())

// 1. Check whether `selectedDate: maxiumDate` accept a `Date?` or `Date` instance.

// 2. Check the number of arguments in `(picker, selectedIndex, selectedValue) in` part
// and what the docs say
let picker = ActionSheetDatePicker.init(title: "Date of Birth", datePickerMode: .date, selectedDate: maxiumDate, doneBlock: { (picker, selectedIndex, selectedValue) in
```

Comment: I have to pass more parameter in ActionSheetDatePicker initializer but I don't what to pass with  Target, Action & Origin

Comment: Read the docs for the library and then pass everything that you need to.

Comment: its a complete function :- let pickers = ActionSheetDatePicker.init(title: <#T##String!#>, datePickerMode: <#T##UIDatePicker.Mode#>, selectedDate: <#T##Date!#>, target: <#T##Any!#>, action: <#T##Selector!#>, origin: <#T##Any!#>)